# Axios - request - replace field by variable --> axios(url,{field <-- variable : data}

Tags: javascript, axios

my variable 'field' isn't recognize, how can i writing this :

```
 axiosPut(url2+"/"+id2,{field:response.data['@id']})
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use brackets notation to specify dynamic key for an object

```
axiosPut(url2+"/"+id2,{[field] :response.data['@id']})
```